# Forward declarations: templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, declaration

When writing a framework I got following problem:
I have `class A` and `class B` wchich  is derived from `class A`.

`class A` has a function wchich returns `B*`.

Of course, it's not difficult:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B; // forward declaration

class A
{
    public:
        B* ReturnSomeData();
};

class B : public A
{
};

// Implementation:

B* A::ReturnSomeData()
{
    return new B; // doesn't matter how the function makes pointer
}

int main()
{
    A sth;

    cout << sth.ReturnSomeData(); // print adress
}
```

However I had to use templates like here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// This "forward declaration":

template <class Number>
class B<Number>;

// cannot be compiled:
// "7 error: 'B' is not a template"

template <class Number>
class A
{
    public:
        B<Number>* ReturnSomeData();
};

template <class Number>
class B : public A<Number>
{
};

// Implementation:

template <class Number>
B<Number>* A<Number>::ReturnSomeData()
{
    return new B<Number>;
}

int main()
{
    A<int> sth;

    cout << sth.ReturnSomeData();
}
```

Look at the code. As you can see I don't know how to deal with unknown by A `B*`. Is it possible to write forward declaration? Or I need something different?

Yes, I searched and I see there are many posts about template declarations but can't find solve for my individual problem. It's a bit complex for me.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your forward declaration is incorrect.  It needs to be:

```
template <class Number>
class B;
       ^ no argument list
```

Comment: Thanks :) It works in this simple example. But I'm still wondering why doesn't it work in my framework. I'll write if I search the reason.

Comment: Ok, I know what I did wrong - the compiler started display "_B is not template type_" instead of "_B is not template_". It was the main problem. It was because in one file there was `class B` declaration (old file wchich I forgot to remake to use templates). That's why I couldn't declare: `template <class Number> B` (compiler knew "untemplatized" B so it didn't let me for new declaration). And because of it I thought a declaration without parameter list is wrong, but it's correct. Thanks again :).